# How to find the first occurence of date which is greater than or eqaul to particular date in text file using shell script

Tags: shell

```
past_date='2013-11-14'
initial_time=$(grep -o -m1  "$past_date [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]" logfile.txt)
```

/* Here I am trying to find the first occurence of date which is greater than or eqaul to '2013-11-14', Above code I have tried ,It is giving only that particular line  of file, If that date is not found It has to give next date which is greater than 2013-11-14 date */

Comment: Are the backquotes on the first line a typo?

Comment: Your distro and version matters for a good answer. Please give more info about your system.

Comment: Here is data of logfile.txt                                      2013-09-16 15:45:14:TomAgent 2.8 r5896 starting ...
2013-09-16 15:45:14 Starting agent install process
2013-11-13 15:45:40 TomAgent 2.8 r5896 starting ...
2013-11-15 15:45:40 Starting agent install process
2013-11-16 12:35:23 TomAgent 2.8 r5896 starting ...
2013-11-17 12:35:23 Starting agent install process
2013-09-17 12:41:32 TomAgent 2.8 r5896 starting ...
2013-09-17 12:41:32 Action daemon detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while read line
do
initial_time=`echo $line | sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/'`
file_content_date=`date -d "$initial_time" +%Y%m%d`
comparison_past_date=`date -d "$past_date" +%Y%m%d`
if [ $comparison_past_date -le $file_content_date ]; then
comparison_start_date=`date -d "$file_content_date" +%Y%m%d`
break
 fi
done < logfile.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
past_date='20131114'
awk '{d=$1;gsub(/-/,"",d);if (d>=p) {print;exit}}' p=$past_date logfile

2013-11-15 15:45:40 Starting agent install process
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use bash, then you might want to try something like:

```
past_date='2013-11-14'
initial_time=$(grep -oP '\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d' < logfile.txt | \
while read LINE ; do if [ "$LINE" '>' "$past_date" ]; then echo $LINE; break; fi ; done)
```